# tr translate characters question with 66 and 99 quotes “ ”

Tags: bash, character, translate, tr

I'm using the command tr to remove punctuation, but it doesn't seem to remove the `66's` and `99's` types of quotes.

Here is the command I use:

```
cat test.txt | tr '[:punct:]' ' '
```

These : `“ ”`

It does remove the regular ones like : `" "`

Any ideas why?

Comment: Hi, I would just like to say, this isn't really the place for asking about bash. Try ask Ubuntu or Superuser (Both by stack exchange). You are more likely to get an answer that will help you

Comment: This is a known problem with GNU `tr`, described in detail with workarounds [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228558/how-to-make-tr-aware-of-non-asciiunicode-characters). Your code would work fine on e.g. macOS.

Answer (score 0):

**This works:**

```
cat test.txt | tr -d '"'
```